# want to create a route in codeigniter so that it gives "route/name-vs-name" where name can any alphabet

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I am building a website with php and codeigniter, want to create a route so that it points to method 
the route will be like `route/name-vs-name` where name can be any name want to do name with regular expression

Need help. This is not working:

```
route/([a-zA-Z]+)-vs-([a-zA-z])
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working" - any error messages?

Comment: You almost got it, literally fixed the regex adding 2 characters. Not sure if flag for closing as a typo or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont play with regular experience. get your uri in controller or get parameter from function as codeigniter propose. and use function url_decode to get proper value. and convert string to array for getting names as you want

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple or errors:

1. You should escape `/` Check [this link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) for more info.
2. The second capturing group only captures 1
   letter.

Check this regex:

```
route\/([a-zA-Z]+)-vs-([a-zA-z]+)
```

BTW, not sure in PHP, but in c# you can make regex case insensitive and it would be easier (the `a-z` would be identical to `a-zA-Z`)